# Selenium + Python3.x Помогите нажать на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

Я только начинаю изучать selenium + python и застрял на том что не могу найти кнопку помогите пожалуйста
[image: Вот код кнопки которую я хочу найти]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
target = driver.find_element_by_class_name('do')
target.click()
```